# Defining a set of random numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I am attempting to use the `sympy.stats` module to help compute the expectation value of an expression. In the simplest form my problem is the following:

I know how to define two normally distributed random variables and compute the expectation

```
from sympy.stats import Normal, E
import sympy as sp
sigma = sp.symbols('sigma', positive=True)

x1 = Normal("x1", 0, sigma)
x2 = Normal("x2", 0, sigma)
print E(x1 * x2)

Out: 0
```

However, I would like to be able to define say `X` which is a vector (or list) of `N` 
normally distributed random variable. The trouble is I need `N` to remain arbitrary so
I can't create a list or anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

The reason I need to do this is that I will be taking summation over the components of X, some of them will be correlated and some won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're looking for something like the following?

```
mu = MatrixSymbol('mu', n, 1)
Sigma = MatrixSymbol('Sigma', n, n)

X = Normal('X', mu, sigma)  # A multivariate normal distribution
```

If so then you're currently out of luck.  SymPy stats doesn't currently support anything more than the combintation of several univariate distributions, we don't handle multivariate distributions in generality.

If you're willing to go numeric then you may find PyMC3 of interest.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't appear any of the alternatives help either. I guess I will have to wait..or do it by hand.

Comment: ...or contribute to SymPy :)

Comment: Okay, that is a fair suggestion. I will look into it this evening - if you have any hints on where about I should start digging that would be appreciated.